# Swift Generic Type Equatable by sorting array

Tags: swift, generics, equality

I'm trying to conform my generic `CustomSet` to Equatable but I get the following error when I try to sort the list array in the Equatable func:

> Ambiguous reference to member '<'

I think the problem is that the compiler has no information on value types when comparing on sort, but I'm not sure how to tell it what it needs. Is this even possible to do on generic types?

The goal is to say `CustomSet` is Equal if `list` contains the exact same values.

```
struct CustomSet<T : Equatable> {
    var list: [T]
    init(_ list: [T]){
        self.list = list
    }
}

extension CustomSet : Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: CustomSet, rhs: CustomSet) -> Bool {
        return lhs.list.count == rhs.list.count && lhs.list.sorted(by: <) == rhs.list.sorted(by: <)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restrict your generic type parameter to `Comparable` to be able to use the `<` operator on elements of `list` and hence sort `list`.

```
struct CustomSet<T : Comparable> {
    var list: [T]
    init(_ list: [T]){
        self.list = list
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about it this way: Equatable lets you tell if two objects are **equal**. Comparable lets you compare two objects to see which one is greater. To sort, you need to be able to compare objects.